# What is the ^@ symbol at the end of my output txt file?

Tags: c++, bash, terminal

I wrote c++ code to read from a text file and then bash code to output it to another file (specifically './executable &> output.txt'). When I print it on the command line it looks fine, but when I check the output file, it has a '^@' symbol at the end of it.

Comment: Where is the code that you wrote?

Comment: How are you sure that your code is not writing this out to `stdout` or `stderr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your program, it's writing a nul character at the end of your file. Then whatever tool you use to check the output is using: [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for non-printable characters.

- `^@` is the notation for the nul character.

We cannot tell more without seeing the code.